# Update scheduled time for azure webjob programmatically

Tags: azure-webjobs

Is there a way to change the scheduled time for a webjob from within an MVC application or is the only way through the azure portal.
I do not mean the initial schedule times, but after deployment change the scheduled time via UI in the Mvc application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always access the WebJobs in your website through the [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API). 
You can trigger the WebJob through a manual call for Triggered Jobs. 
You can also upload a new zip through the API in case your schedule changes.

In order to change the schedule, you'll have to go through the portal, or redeploy the WebJob with the new schedule. You can obviously do this via Visual Studio or using the API.

There's more information on WebJobs [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx, for this answer i'll try to create a UI that works with the API.
Are there some sample projects on the web?

Comment: @DannyDeBoiserie I updated the answer with the link to the Kudu WebJobs project that contains a lot of resources on how to use the API. There are also examples in the github repo.

Comment: Can i change start time of scheduler which is already running regularly (with no end date)?

Comment: @ManirajSS yes you can change it in the json file, or in the scheduler itself in Azure.